# Can I use NX CLI for both Angular and React apps in one Nx workspace?

Tags: angular, reactjs, angular-cli, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I tried the below, but got some errors.

1. create a Nx workspace: `npx create-nx-workspace@latest myworkspace`, and
   select to use Angular CLI
2. generate angular app: `yarn add --dev @nrwl/angular && yarn ng g @nrwl:angular:app myapp-ng`
   I can see a `angular.json` for the workspace setup similarly as Angular CLI, and `yarn start/build` all works
3. add react capability: `yarn add -D @nrwl/react`
4. generate another react app: `yarn ng g @nrwl/react:app myapp-react`
   but I got the below error saying Nx workspace not recognized.

I guess it's trying to find the workspace config instead from `workspace.json` (an empty Nx workspace has such setup).

Is this a bug in Nx or is it a supported case to include both Angular and React in one workspace? I can find some blogs/docs about it though...

**UPDATE:**

Okay, just realized that I made a mistake here :(

At step 4, I was running `yarn nx g ...` instead of `ng g ...`. Then there's a warning as below when using `nx` command in a NG CLI workspace:

```
yarn nx g @nrwl/react:app react2 --dry-run
yarn run v1.12.3
$ nx g @nrwl/react:app react2 --dry-run

>  NX   NOTE  Nx didn't recognize the command, forwarding on to the Angular CLI.
```

the react app can actually be created successfully using NG CLI. And, I think the warning makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of NX are you using? Everything should work well, look at the NX example: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples

It uses: `"@nrwl/angular": "8.4.0",` as well as `"@nrwl/react": "8.4.0",` and consists of two apps:

1. Carts (React):
   [image: Carts app - React]
2. Products (Angular):
   [image: Products App - Angular]

Comment: I figured out that it's my mistake and that's only a warning note instead of errors. Sorry for the mistake and thanks for your answer, especially the link to the example repo. I guess the warning is thrown when using `nx` command in a NG CLI workspace, right? I already updated the OP.